# Is it Possible to Check Received fields are Empty or Null Without If

Tags: java, if-statement, null

I am receiving list of fields. Near About to 60 fields.

From that I have to check 50 fields that are they null or empty, if not then I ll have to add them also in DB table.

Right now I am doing it manually using if condition. I am just thinking to do so, not implemented still yet.

Is there any better option then it ?

My Code :

```
if(ValidateData.checkIsNullOrEmpty(command.getSubscriptionStartYear())){

}
if(ValidateData.checkIsNullOrEmpty(command.getSubscriptionPeriod())){

}
if(ValidateData.checkIsNullOrEmpty(command.getExpectedArrivalTimeOfIssues())){

}
.....
.....

if(ValidateData.checkIsNullOrEmpty(command.getMaxNoOfClaims())){

}
```

Here `command` is class which receives Data from source.

Here `ValidateData` is a `class` :

It's method definition :

```
public static boolean checkIsNullOrEmpty(Integer arg){
    if(arg != null) return true;
    return false;
}

public static boolean checkIsNullOrEmpty(String arg){
     if(!arg.trim().equals("") || !arg.trim().equals(" ") || arg.trim() != null) return true;
     return false;
}
```

If anyone guide me or suggest me that is there any better option available ??

Comment: Would be helpful to se the class code of `command`

Comment: How about using reflection to invoke all get*** and then call your validate methods? Also if you can then try using Apache's StringUtils.isEmpty and/or StringUtils.isBlank

Comment: @mprabhat seems a bit harsh to use reflection when you have the class just for validate, no?

Comment: Not really, OP wants a more generic way instead of adding new if code in his logic

Answer (score 1):

create a function like this:

```
public static bool AllNull(object... something)
{
    for(var v :something)
       if(v!=null){
         if(v instanceof Integer)
           // do integer validation
       }else
         //Err msg
}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
if (AllNull(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6))
{
    // ...
}
```

if you want to be specific, separate strings and integers and make separate function like this one for each type you need

### Edit

as i understod from your comment, u don't know [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

> varargs are useful for any method that needs to deal with an
>   indeterminate number of objects. One good example is String.format.

Comment: but here some are Integer & some are String. So how to tackle with it ?

Comment: @user3145373ツ look at my last edit. use object and not integer/string

Comment: I like the use of Lambda, but still, you will have to manually put each variables in an array. Plus, if you add a variable, you would have to edit the code as well.

Comment: In function what is `params` ?

Comment: @ortis yes, but if you've added a field, you already edited the code :)

Comment: @user3145373ツ look at my edit, and open MSDN on params

Comment: @No Idea For Name OP said the fields came form a DB. So each time you add (or remove btw) a field, you have to edit the code. Also, `params` is not Java, nor `foreach` :)

Comment: but `params` is for c# !! It's Java. Sorry but I am bit confused so.

Comment: @user3145373ツ i've edited the answer. again, sorry for confusion

Comment: Suppose in above code I am checking `v != null` then I want to set it's value in current class variable `v1`, then what to do ? i can't do `v1 = v`. I have to `assign their value to other if they are not null` in if condition so what to do for that ?

Comment: @user3145373ツ use typeof or instanceof. check my edit

Answer (score 0):

if you can edit command, you can mark each field that you want to check null with @NotNull, then use java reflect api to get all fields marked with @NotNull, and check whether some fields null or not

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution for your problem is using Java Reflect.
Here is sample code to validate all field of an instance by Java Reflect.
Example I have one instance(pojo) of object PojoObj.

```
PojoObj pojo = new PojoObj("one1", 2, null, 4, "five", "Six");
```

Validate all fields by Java Reflect.

```
Class<PojoObj>  aClass = PojoObj.class;
      Field[] fields = aClass.getDeclaredFields();
      for(Field field : fields) {
          Object value = field.get(pojo);
          Object type = field.getType();
          if(value == null) {
              System.out.println(field.getName() + " is null");
          } else {
              System.out.println(field.getName() + " is instanceof " + type + " and value = " + value);
          }
      }
```

Output:

```
fieldOne is instanceof class java.lang.String and value = one1
fieldTwo is instanceof long and value = 2
fieldThree is null
fieldFour is instanceof int and value = 4
fieldFive is instanceof class java.lang.String and value = five
fieldSix is instanceof class java.lang.String and value = Six
```

Comment: but how to set variable value to other target variable if it's not null ?